# Obtain a service account credentials within a Cloud Functions to call a google service outside GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-api-python-client

My scenario: I need to call the Google DBM API using `google-api-python-client` from a Cloud Function using a service account.

**Update**

Here the sample code I trying to run:

```
import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth.transport import requests

API_NAME = 'doubleclickbidmanager'
API_VERSION = 'v1.1'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/doubleclickbidmanager']

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)

print(credentials.service_account_email)
# prints "default"

credentials.refresh(requests.Request())
print(credentials.service_account_email)
# prints "[service-account]@[project].iam.gserviceaccount.com"

service = build(API_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)
service.queries().listqueries().execute()
# local: return the queries
# in CF: Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "insufficientPermissions"
```

When I run locally setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=keyfile.json` works fine.

But when running in the Cloud Function I got the 403 error.

The `keyfile.json` use the same service account `[service-account]@[project].iam.gserviceaccount.com` setted in the Cloud Function.

Comment: What do you mean by `But the emails in the returned credentials was default`? Can you explain and show a log trace and how you print this log?

Comment: I meant the credential.service_account_email=`default` not the service account email. I suppose this property should be equal to FUNCTION_IDENTITY env variable

Answer (score 3):

You have to force the library to generate a token to force it to fulfill all its fields. For this, simply call a retry, like this

```
import google.auth
credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)

from google.auth.transport import requests
credentials.refresh(requests.Request())
print(credentials._service_account_email)

build(API_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: Running with `credentials.refresh` locally and setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the keyfile works fine. But when run in the Cloud Functions I got 403 error on the API call.

Comment: Did you get the correct service account email? If so, what the rest of the code. Which API are you trying to call?

Comment: I've checked the service account email, is the same in the keyfile.json and in the Cloud Function. I updated the question with the sample code.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have DBM account. I tried it. I activate the API. I got 403 but it's normal, I don't have account and i'm unauthorized. I guess for an issue in your DBM config instead in your code. Do you have IP checks on DBM or something that can differ from your local origin and the Cloud Function origin?

Comment: Thank you so much, this should be clearly documented in GCP